# Upgrading grafana v4 to v5 - or should skip and go straight to v7?

Tags: kubernetes, grafana

Playing catch up with Grafana versions, (Kubernetes v1.16.15 clusters)
Currently running in PRODUCTION is **very** out of date (v4)
I'm only upgrading now, and refactoring all my configs for the "new" provisioning.

Should I just upgrade to v5 and release in PROD, and then incrementally upgrade again to v6?
or skip v5 just straight to v7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [official docs](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/installation/upgrading/#upgrade-grafana) there are some functions/solutions that went deprecated from one version to another. You should take a look when upgrading to make sure that you are ready for it.

Other than that, there are two ways to get your Grafana to v7:

1. Step by step upgrade:

- [Backup Database](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/installation/upgrading/#database-backup)
- Backup Grafana configuration file (i.e grafana.ini)
- Perform the update/upgrade depending on [the chosen method](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/installation/upgrading/#ubuntu-or-debian).

2. If that won't work, you can also do a fresh install on top of an existing one or remove the current version, install the latest one and than check grafana.ini file.

If you choose the 1st option than please notice that it is considered safer to upgrade one major version at the time. Also, the database/configuration backup is always recommended.

**EDIT:**

If you are using [Grafana Community Kubernetes Helm Charts](https://github.com/grafana/helm-charts#grafana-community-kubernetes-helm-charts) than notice that [Upgrading an existing Release to a new major version](https://github.com/grafana/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/grafana/README.md#upgrading-an-existing-release-to-a-new-major-version) requires the **Helm v3** (>= 3.1.0) starting from Grafana v6.0.0.

Comment: sorry forgot to mention, using helm (v2) for grafana installs/upgrades. All dashboards and configs are stored under version control. So I guess it will be some trial and error with the helm charts values and templates?

Comment: @siwasaki Was the info above helpful for you?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Wytrzymały Wiktor
I'm taking the "safe route" upgrading v4->v5 first.  New functions and configuration change impacts are too great (as I said system is very out of date!)

Re-factoring all my helm charts, and getting old dashboards re-imported to v5 DB,and backing up everything as you advise.

v5 will be released to PROD users, and then will start looking at v6 upgrade soon after.